# how to download images over http to android cache and display later?

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I am new to android and I have a scenario here. I have an application that shows a list of items and on click of each list item, opens up an activity that will show an image and few other details. I have made this app in such a way that it will work offline.

But in case of Images, I used Android Universal Image Loader Library, but for this I see that the methods `loadImage` and `displayImage` need to be bound to an UI element. I want the app to download all the images when there is network and then when I open any `ListView` item in offline mode then I want the image to be picked from `cache` and displayed.

Can anyone of you suggest a way I can achieve this. On one of the similar queries I came across android `executorService`. Should I be applying this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use aquery or picasso library for this

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading refer this link

Comment: use cacheInMemory() method in your Universal Image Loader Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

aq.id(R.id.image1).image(imageUrl, true, true);

Where true, true is memoryCache and fileCache.

Comment: Thanks I shall check this. But Looks like I have to give the resource id here. In my situation I have multiple items that dynamically get added so I am not sure of the resource id. Also, I am looking for something that will download all the images into cache and then I can access them only when I open up a screen.

Comment: you can also point it on ImageView object. Check the link I gave you there is a lot of info about it.

Comment: I used the `Prefetch` feature of aQuery. Achieved what I wanted. Thanks @JakubW

Answer (score 0):

You can able to download the bitmap using Universal image loader, here is the part of the code,

```
imageLoader.displayImage(profilePic, profileImage, options,
                            new ImageLoadingListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                        View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                    // loadedImage - is the downladed bitmap, you can use this for  your further implementation.
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri,
                                        View view) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri,
                                        View view, FailReason failReason) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri,
                                        View view) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Thanks @Aerrow, in your example I have to specify the imageView where I want the image to be shown. But In my case I want all the images downloaded first and then I will set the image to imageView when that view is launched.